# Magento 2 ExportButton component Product grid not working

Tags: admin, magento2.2, uicomponent, product-grid

I have added ExportButton on admin product grid and when i click on export it shows error 
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with this alias is already declared.

I have added the button in

> app/code/Mycompany/Gridexport/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
   <exportButton name="export_button">  
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">product_listing.product_listing.product_columns.ids</item>  
                </item>
            </argument>
    </exportButton> 
</listingToolbar>
```

But When i click on export button I get following error

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
>   (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A joined field with
>   this alias is already declared.
>
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): A
>   joined field with this alias is already declared.
>   generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductCollection/Interceptor.php(973):
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Collection\AbstractCollection->joinField('qty',
>   'cataloginventor...', 'qty', 'product_id=enti...',
>   '{{table}}.stock...', 'left')
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/Ui/DataProvider/Product/AddQuantityFieldToCollection.php(27):
>   Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection\Interceptor->joinField('qty',
>   'cataloginventor...', 'qty', 'product_id=enti...',
>   '{{table}}.stock...', 'left')
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider.php(91):
>   Magento\CatalogInventory\Ui\DataProvider\Product\AddQuantityFieldToCollection->addField(Object(Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductCollection\Interceptor),
>   'qty', NULL)
>   generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/ProductDataProvider/Interceptor.php(37):
>   Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\ProductDataProvider->addField('qty',
>   NULL)

Comment: Did you got the solution?

Comment: Any One got the solution? Please share it.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: try catch should help as joinField method throws an exception if the alias is already used